# How to run multiple functions to return respective lists in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pool, simultaneous

In the example code, I would like to run 4 functions in parallel and return list values for each. Is the multiprocessing package appropriate for this task? If so how do I implement it?

Example Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func_a(num):
    return([1+num,2+num,3+num])

def func_b(num):
    return([10+num,11+num,12+num])

def func_c(num):
    return([20+num,21+num,22+num])

def func_d(num):
    return([30+num,31+num,32+num])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    list_a = ???
    list_b = ???
    list_c = ???
    list_d = ???

    full_list = []
    for item in list_a:
        full_list.append(item)
    for item in list_b:
        full_list.append(item)
    for item in list_c:
        full_list.append(item)
    for item in list_d:
        full_list.append(item)
```

Any information much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you pass a different number to each function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [Process Pools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool), you need to submit all of the jobs to the pool, and then wait for all of the results.

I'm not sure what arguments you want to pass to these functions, since it isn't in your question or your code, but I'll just make up something arbitrary.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    result_a = pool.apply_async(func_a, (23,))
    result_b = pool.apply_async(func_b, (42,))
    result_c = pool.apply_async(func_c, (fractions.Fraction(1, 2),))
    result_d = pool.apply_async(func_a, (1j * math.pi,))

    full_list = []
    for item in result_a.get():
        full_list.append(item)
    for item in result_b.get():
        full_list.append(item)
    for item in result_c.get():
        full_list.append(item)
    for item in result_d.get():
        full_list.append(item)
```

You can dramatically simplify this in multiple ways (e.g., each of those `for` loops can be replaced by a single call to `extend`, or you can just write `full_list = result_a.get() + result_b.get() + result_c.get() + result_d.get())`, but this is the smallest change to your existing code that works. (And if you really want to simplify this code, I think you'd be happier with `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` in the first place.)

Comment: The args for apply_async need to be wrapped in an iterable, e.g. `pool.apply_async(func_a, [23])`.

Comment: @AlexHall Oops, I always forget which methods in `multiprocessing` take `args` and which take `*args`… thanks; fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (since my question was never answered) that each function receives the same number:

```
def apply_func(f):
    return f(3)

full_list = sum(pool.map(apply_func, [func_a, func_b, func_c, func_d]), [])
```